# Test Select list Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm attempting to test the behavior of a dynamic `<select>` element. The element is initially built with a static set of options. However, this list is modified (sorted) depending on dynamic criteria.

The test fails intermittently (more often than not). When it fails, it is apparent that the test fires before the JS that orders the list has completed.

```
cy.get(this.selectors.chooseYourLocation)
  .select(1).invoke('val')
  .should('eq', '91dfda2e-dab7-11e7-83ce-fa163e96b1b7');
```

I've been able to mitigate the failures by adding `cy.wait(3000);`  before the `.get`

However, this is considered an anti-pattern and I'd like to not do it.
Any suggestions on how to ensure that the JS that sorts the  options has been completed before attempting to test for the expected sorted value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing required is an **increase in the timeout** on the `.select()` command.

Make it slightly longer than the expected maximum wait for option loading.

---

A simple example - make this dynamic [`<select>`: The HTML Select element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) and set with a loading time of 5 seconds:

```js
<label for="pet-select">Choose a pet:</label>

<select name="pets" id="pet-select">
  <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
</select>

<script>
  setTimeout(() => {
    const select = document.querySelector('select')
    const options = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Hamster', 'Parrot', 'Spider', 'Goldfish']
    options.forEach(value => {
      const option = document.createElement('option')
      option.innerText = value
      option.value = value.toLowerCase()
      select.append(option)
    })
  }, 5_000)     // simulating 5 second loading time
</script>
```

Now add a 5 or 6 second `timeout` in the test:

```js
cy.get('select')
  .select('Parrot', {timeout:5_000})

cy.get('select')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', 'Parrot')
```

---

**NOTE** Cypress says

> It is **unsafe** to chain further commands that rely on the subject after `.select()`

so split the test code as shown above.

---

#### Waiting for options list to be sorted

After your comment, I see that the sorting process causing your issue.

Add a `.should(callback)` to the options list to make the test wait for sorting to finish.

```js
cy.get('option', {timeout:10_000})  // an appropriate timeout on this command
  .should('have.length.gt', 1)     // only needed if options are fetched from API
  .should($options => {          
  
    // this will retry until sort is complete
    const values = [...$options].map(el => el.getAttribute('value'))
    const sorted = [...values].sort()
    expect(values).to.deep.eq(sorted)
  })

cy.get('select')
  .select('Parrot', {timeout:5_000})

cy.get('select')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', 'Parrot')
```

---

#### Why not add a timeout to .should()

You mention in comments:

> I have to set a `{timout: xxxx}` on the statement that is checks the condition (.e.g., `.should(xxxxxxx)`)

This is the wrong way to think about it.

Cypress does not have a `timeout` for `.should()` which is an ***assertion***. Timeouts only apply to ***queries***.

Think about `.should()` as an ***extension*** to the query. It inherits the `timeout` from the query and keeps retrying for that duration.

This makes sense, because you can't have a `.should()` without some query in front of it.

Comment: Very good points. However, the solution you outlined falls short of solving the problem. 
You suggested a split code- That causes a problem; the {timeout: 5000} has to be attached to the check for the specific value that is being tested for. 

Adding a timout() to the select alone doesn't accomplish a thing. The structure is already assured and will always be there. 
The problem is that I'm sorting the <select> list and need to check expected results from that. 
I have to set a {timout: xxxx} on the statement that is checks the condition (.e.g., .should(xxxxxxx)

Comment: I have added the step to ensure sorting is complete before performing the `.select()`.

Comment: In general, for any action that takes some time - add a `should()` expression to make sure it is complete.

Answer (score 1):

you can wait for the element to check the number of items in the list

```
cy.get('.datalist').find('tr').should('have.length', 4) // equal to
//or
cy.get('.datalist').find('tr').should('have.gt', 4) // greater than
//or
cy.get('.datalist').find('tr').should('have.gte', 4) // greater than or equal
```

or using cy.intercept() to wait for the network that the element list is using to completely load

```
cy.intercept('GET', '/my-list-request-network').as('getListRequest');
cy.wait('getListRequest')
```